# Randomly raising Internal Server Error 500. How to debug?

Tags: ajax, apache, zend-framework, nginx

Recently I moved my zend app from simple hosting to azure, configured to process requests via nginx->haproxy->apache chain. nginx, haproxy and apache are docker containers. While loading the application makes 20-30 AJAX requests to different controllers. Here's the common init method I use in controllers:

```
public function init()
{
    $this->sa = System_Auth::getInstance();
    $this->data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $this->current = $this->sa->getCurrent();
    $this->data['customer_id'] = $this->current->customer ? $this->current->customer->id : $this->current->id;

    $this->_helper->contextSwitch()
        ->addActionContext('test', 'json')
        ->setAutoJsonSerialization(true)
        ->initContext();
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
}
```

So there is nothing interesting in it. But every time I load application about 3 or 4 AJAX requests return 500 error. Each time different requests failed with 500 error. Apache and nginx logs are empty. And I can't dump data passed to controller because failed controllers aren't even called.
Anyone has idea?

Comment: 500 internal server is a HTTP error status code, hence the apache/nginx error log will show you something. Try to read the live feeds of error log using "tail -f" while you are getting 500 error on browser

Comment: Leo, no luck, 500 error isn't logged

Answer (score 0):

OK quys, finally it was fixed.

**Where happened:**
HaProxy and round-robined mariaDB Cluster Master-Master-Master

**What happened:**
Some queries randomly failed each time

**Why:**
sql_mode=only_full_group_by was found on one of three mysql servers

Earlier I cleared sql_mode variable on all servers, but it seems later it was restored when one of servers was restarted. And variables aren't replicable, you should manually change them on each server*

*It may be possible but I don't know right now